# javaCV in NETBEANS on windowsXP platform

Tags: java, opencv

Dear friends...
           Here  i am trying to use openCV in java using NETBEANS(windows XP).., For that i did the following ..

[B]1-Install OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe in C:\openCV
2-Then i put the javaCV and JNA in the library (System path.)
3-The i use thae following code in the netbeans[/B]

[CODE]

package samplejavacv;

import java.io.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.cxcore.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.cv.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.highgui.*;

public class sample {

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    try {

        IplImage Iimg=cvLoadImage("C:\\Documents and Settings\\All                                                               Users\\Documents\\My Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Sunset.jpg");

    }
    catch(Exception f) {

        System.out.print(f.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

[/CODE]

4- But i got the following exception

[CODE]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'cxcore': The specified module could not be found.

```
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:163)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:199)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.jna.Loader.load(Loader.java:44)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.jna.cxcore.<clinit>(cxcore.java:113)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.jna.highgui.<clinit>(highgui.java:73)
    at samplejavacv.sample.main(sample.java:49)
```

Java Result: 1

[/CODE]

5-Then what should i do ....please help
6- Remember some site mention that it need to build the openCV , if it need how can i do that please help...

Anyway thanks in advance  .....
Happynew year

Answer (score 0):

You will need compiled *.DLL (for 32 or AMD 64 windows platform or *.SO for e.g. linux) files like:

```
-cv.dll
-cvaux.dll
-cvauxd.dll
-cvd.dll
-cxcore.dll
-cxcored.dll
-cxts.dll
-cxtsd.dll
-highgui.dll
-highguid.dll
-md.dll
-ml.dll
```

than run your JAVA VM with -Djna.library.path=c:\path\to\your\dlls\directory. E.g.:

```
 java -Djna.library.path=c:\path\to\your\dlls\directory -cp=. Test
```